# <h:inputText> enabled/disabled - change background color

Tags: java, html, css, jsf, richfaces

can I change background color for disabled `<h:inputText>`?

I've tried to do this way:

```
<h:inputText value="test" disabled="true" styleClass="input"/>
```

css contains:

```
input:disabled {background-color:blue;}
input:enabled {background-color:red;}
```

and result is:

[image]

reason, why I'm trying to change the background is, that since I've installed richfaces, disabled and enabled has the same color, both are white

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<td class="width10">Směna:</td>
<td class="width15"><input name="bde:j_idt100" value="2011-05-18-S2" size="13" style="background-color: blue; color: red;" disabled="disabled" type="text"><input id="bde:shift" name="bde:shift" type="hidden"></td>
<td><input name="bde:j_idt102" value="ranní" class="input2" size="13" disabled="disabled" type="text"><input name="bde:j_idt103" value="admin" class="input2" size="13" disabled="disabled" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowEven">
<td class="width5"><input id="bde:f1" name="bde:f1" value="F1" tabindex="2" title="Novy pracovnik - vymaze vsechna pole formulare" class="btninput" type="submit"></td>
<td class="width10">Pracovník:</td>
<td class="width15">
<input id="bde:worker" name="bde:worker" class="input" size="13" tabindex="1" onblur="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'mojarra.ab(this,event,\'blur\',\'@this\',\'bde:inputName\')','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'blur\',\'@this\',\'bde:inputSname\')','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'blur\',\'@this\',\'bde:inputDep\')','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'blur\',\'@this\',\'bde:reportErr\')')" type="text"></td>
```

Graphic differences between richfaces generated code and HTML:

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *reason, why I'm trying to change the background is, that since I've installed richfaces, disabled and enabled has the same color, both are white*

RichFaces ships with its own [basic skinning](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming). On RichFaces 4.0 you can disable it altogether by the following context parameters in `web.xml`.

This disables the standard skin stylesheets (see chapter 6.6.1 of the linked developer guide)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This disables the component specific skin stylesheets (see chapter 6.6.2)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you however don't want to disable the basic skinning for some reason, but rather want to override specific CSS property/properties, then you need to specify exactly those property/properties in your own CSS. Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), you can rightclick the element of interest and choose *Inspect Element* to get all definied CSS properties in the right hand side of the bottom console.

In this particular case, the `input` has a `background-image` property pointing to a particular URL. You need to override it like as follows:

```
input { 
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right and I çan disable the skin now. And If I only need the input style override in my css? I'm not able to find where are inputs defined in richfaces..

Comment: It's the `skinning.ecss` file which definies the basic style. Check once again with Firebug. Rightclick the input element, choose *Inspect Element*, on the right hand side you'll see applied CSS definitions.

Comment: yes, i've found the problem: background-image: url("/PORTAL/rfRes/inputBackgroundImage.png.xhtml?v=4.0.0.Final&db=eAFjZL!AyMDN-P8!4!-P714C6f!!GZgAYeQKqw__&ln=org.richfaces.images"); Can I save the option disabled by fireBug?

Comment: If you don't want to disable the `skinning.ecss` for some reason, you'll need to override yourself by defining `background-image: none;` on the same CSS selector as RichFaces used (just `input {}` probably?).

Comment: Could you extend your answer with override suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Try with this

```
<h:inputText value="test" disabled="disabled" style="background-color:blue; color:red;" />
```

Comment: Thank you! But it changed only text color, background is still the same :(

Comment: still the same (please take a look at the new picture on my post) :)

Comment: Can you send me generated HTML for that

Comment: `<input name="bde:j_idt100" value="2011-05-18-S2" size="13" style="background-color: blue; color: red;" disabled="disabled" type="text">` works for me..Which browser you are using, tested in a chrome 11.0.696.68 , FF 4  ,IE 6

Comment: FF4. HTML works here too, but when it's generated from JSF, it doesn't... it's strange :-/

Comment: No, it doesn't. There must be some problem in style generated by richfaces (sac or cssparser, i dont understand how it is working). When I copy code generated to the separated html file and start it, it works fine!! When I connect it with css file, it works too, but without richfaces graphic improvement....

Comment: I've edited my post - now you can see difference between richfaces generated HTML and HTML design :)

Comment: is there any CSS that RF applied to it ?

Comment: surely, but i have no idea where :]

Comment: so I have to find, where in richfaces styles is inputtext defined... anyway thanks, your help was usefull because i've remembered to test output using HTML code :)

Comment: :) Well you can still do one thing. load jsf and inspect its style using firebug, and load the html and see the style applied. It would be pretty easier

Comment: aha, I've found the <link href="/PORTAL/rfRes/skinning.ecss.xhtml?db=eAHL6rC8BQAEkAIG" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> using fireBug (THANKS!!!), and it seems that's it. It consist its own css style for inputs.....