# how to set row colours of table in skin file richfaces

Tags: richfaces, skinning, jsf-1.2

can please anyone can tell me to how set the row colors of the table using Skin of richfaces? in which file and what property i have to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to inspect your table using firebug and override its style in your CSS file. Something like (not exactly this):

```
.rf-dt-c {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Or you can create your own style for `<rich:dataTable>`, for example:

```
.richTable {
  width: 100%;
}
  .richTable .rowEven {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .richTable .rowOdd {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
  }
  .richTable .active-row {
    background-color: #FFEBDA !important;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

set the style for your `<rich:dataTable>`:

```
<rich:dataTable id="table" var="item" value="#{bean.model}" styleClass="richTable">
  ...
</rich:dataTable>
```

using `jQuery` style the rows (even, odd, active) as you need:

```
<rich:jQuery selector=".richTable tr:odd" query="addClass('rowOdd')" />
<rich:jQuery selector=".richTable tr:even" query="addClass('rowEven')" />
<rich:jQuery selector=".richTable tr" event="mouseover" query="jQuery(this).addClass('active-row')"/>
<rich:jQuery selector=".richTable tr" event="mouseout" query="jQuery(this).removeClass('active-row')"/>
```

and of course add the `jQuery` to your view:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.4.4.js'></script>
```

Comment: it means i have to go with CSS. there is no way to change the skin.properties or XCSS file to achieve this thing?

Comment: I don't know, I've asked to the similar thing months before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043214/hinputtext-enabled-disabled-change-background-color), but got the similar answer as you now :-) to edit your css and override richfaces styles. And it's realy working, clearly and conveniently